# C Fork Usage With User Input

Tags: c, shell, input, process, fork

I am trying to write a shell script in 
C language. In short details, if user enters a command I send it to the system() call, if user enters more than one command like "ls;whoami" I parse it and create child processes to execute all of them. Now it works but my methods such as gets() and getting input by the user does not seem well and when I put multi commands, prompt text becomes unseen. Do you have any suggestion or if you see any mistakes or wrong usage because I am not the C guy then I would be grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define RESET   "\033[0m"
#define BOLDGREEN   "\033[1m\033[32m"      /* Bold Green */
#define BOLDMAGENTA "\033[1m\033[35m"      /* Bold Magenta */

char input[50];
char command[50];
char *inputget;
char *dotcomma;
char *p;
pid_t pid;

void welcome(){
   char* welcomestr = "\n\TEST\n\n";
   printf("%s%s%s",BOLDMAGENTA,welcomestr,RESET);
}

void prompt(){
   char *username = getenv("USER");
   char hostname[1024];
   gethostname(hostname, 1024);
   char currentDirectory[256];
   getcwd(currentDirectory, 256);
printf("%s%s@%s%s%s ~%s $ %s",BOLDGREEN,username,hostname,RESET,BOLDBLUE,currentDirectory,RESET);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    inputget=input;

    welcome();
    prompt();

    gets(inputget);

    if(argc == 1) {

    while(strcmp(inputget, "quit")!=0){
            p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n");

        while(p != NULL){
            pid_t parent = getpid();
            pid = fork();

            if (pid==-1){
                perror("failed to fork");
            }
            else if (pid==0){
                system(p);                                    
                exit(0);       
            }else{  
                p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n");
            }
        }
                    wait(NULL);     

        prompt();
        scanf("%s",input);

        inputget=input;
    }

    exit(0);
    }else{
        //get argc 2 and and read-run commands from text.file
    }
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `gets` again in 2018, this is dangerous deprecated function, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: The prompt remains unseen because your `printf` line in `prompt` does not end with `\n` which flushes stdout. Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` in `prompt`.

Comment: You have to do the `wait(NULL)` in the `else { p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n"); }` block. Do `else { wait(NULL); p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n"); }`

Comment: @Pablo yes that is it. Can you explain the fault by the way, thank you so much. EDIT: When I do that, processes are not running at the same time, it works in the order

Comment: As promised, I've written an answer explaining the problem in further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with the worst part: using `gets`. Don't use this function anymore,
it's dangerous and deprecated. You should use `fgets` instead.

```
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
```

---

There is no reason why any of these variables

```
char input[50];
char command[50];
char *inputget;
char *dotcomma;
char *p;
pid_t pid;
```

have to be global variables, declare them in `main`.

Stream buffers like `stdout` are buffered, content is physically written on
the device once the buffer is full or you call `fflush` to flush the buffer.
One exception is `stdout` when is connected to a terminal, in that case `printf`
will flush immediately when a newline is printed. That's why you almost always
see that the format of `printf` statements end with `\n`, like

```
printf("Your age is %d\n", age);
```

When you don't want to print a newline, because you are printing something like
a prompt, then you should flush `stdout` yourself.

```
void prompt(){
    char *username = getenv("USER");
    char hostname[1024];
    gethostname(hostname, 1024);
    char currentDirectory[256];
    getcwd(currentDirectory, 256);
    printf("%s%s@%s%s%s ~%s $ %s",BOLDGREEN,username,hostname,RESET,BOLDBLUE,currentDirectory,RESET);
    fflush(stdout);  // <-- you need this here
}
```

---

The last thing is where you are executing `wait`. The problem is the
synchronization between the children and the parent process. Once a child is
created, it begins to run immediately. If the child is also printing to `stdout`
and you don't synchronize with the parent, then there's no guarantee which
output will be printed first.

In your case, if the user enters `cmd1;cmd2;cmd3`, you are forking 3 times
but you are only doing **one** `wait` after you've forked all children. That means
that the three children will run concurrently and the order of their output is
undefined. After all children are forked, you finally do `wait(NULL)`, but this
only waits for one child, then you execute `prompt()` but remember, the other
children might be still running and hence the output of the prompt might come
before the output of the other children that are running. That is perhaps what
you've been observing.

If you want to emulate the shell, then `cmd2` can only start after `cmd1` is
finished and `cmd3` only after `cmd2` is finished. Only when the three commands
are finished you can execute `prompt()`. That means that you have to wait for
every child to end before the next child can be forked. That's why you have to
move the `wait` in the parent block before the next `fork` is called.

```
// "quit\n" because fgets does not remove the newline
while(strcmp(inputget, "quit\n") != 0) {
    p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n");

    while(p != NULL) {
        if(p[0] == 0)
        {
            // handles "empty fields", when
            // two delimiters come one after
            // the other 
            p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n");
            continue;
        }

        pid = fork();

        if (pid==-1) {
            perror("failed to fork");
        }
        else if (pid==0) {
            system(p);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            wait(NULL);  // <-- here the parent waits
                         //     until the child is finished
            p = strsep(&inputget, ";\n");
        }
    }

    prompt();
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);

    inputget = input;
}
```

Also note that I'm not using `scanf` here. `scanf("%s"...` reads until the first
non-white character, so a command like `cat /etc/fstab` will only read `cat` and
your shell will only execute `cat` and it would block until you close `stdin`
(by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). The next time, `scanf` won't wait
for user input and will read `/etc/fstab` instead and try to execute
`/etc/fstab`, which will fail, as `/etc/fstab` is not a script or binary.
That's why it's better to use `fgets`.

I'd also use a longer buffer for the user input, depending on the command
length, 49 bytes is too short. I'd use 1024 or more. Or you can use `getline` to
fetch a whole line without the worry about buffer sizes.